# How to upload bigger size image with post?

Tags: support, images

I just want to upload image that at least 7.15 MB. but it's completed with one message removing frame.

Is there size restriction for image uploading?

Comment: it's take long time and doesn't return any output.

Comment: Compress your image using any image editor tool then upload it.

Comment: this solution works..thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you hit the size limit it means you tried to upload animated GIF or PNG, which according to imgur (our image host) [faq](https://imgur.com/faq#size) is indeed limited:

> The maximum non-animated file size you can upload is 10MB. However, if the image is over 1MB then it will automatically be compressed or resized to 1MB, for better viewing on the net. **The maximum animated file size (both GIF and PNG) is 2MB**.

You can find other image host who allows bigger animations, or convert to short video upload to YouTube and post a link.